# Astronomical animations of deep space objects

Tags: photography, deep-sky-observing, nasa

Is there any real animations from NASA or others (not simulation or Artist's impression) like this

https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a000000/a004400/a004442/frames/730x730_1x1_30p/

or this

https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a000000/a004000/a004038/frames/4096x4096_1x1_30p/304A-Frames/

for deep space objects like galaxies, nebula, Binary star, etc?

Or it is really not possible to get animation, because it is too far and everything is looks very slow from earth?

Because whatever I found so far is only solar system animations (planets, moon, Sun, etc), software simulation or Artist's impression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are! Here are some examples:

- A [giant flare in the XZ Tauri system](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hs-2000-32-a-animated.gif)
- The [light echo from the outburst of V838 Monocerotis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpWROGf5bPk)
- The [planetary system at HR 8799](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVgKidAuf4o)

The first two are obviously sequences of still images taken a while apart, the third one uses interpolation to smooth out the motion.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!
Why is it so difficult to find videos like this?

Comment: This one even better for V838
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqfGbTvihf4

Comment: What makes these videos so difficult to find, is that they are difficult to make. And this is because relative to the fast scales of objects be cane resolve outside our solar system stuff just moves pretty slowly. So there is not my changing on the timescale of a few years.